# Wix RegistrySearch on multiple places

Tags: wix

Is it possible to search the registry in multiple places for a value?

I want to get the value from key X, but if it's not there, I want to get it from key Y.

Comment: This question arises when reading [Where to Install?](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/getting-started/where-to-install/)  in the WiX Toolset Tutorial. But the ["answer"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7980642/2932052) seems very unsatisfying. Do you know anything more about this since then?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can author a number of RegistrySearch elements under a single Property element. Remember that if a number of keys/values are found, the last will end up as a property values. So, you should probably start with the key/value which will most likely exist, and add those which might not underneath. Play with it before putting into production :-)